# r - média de uma variável em relação aos valores de outra variável em um data frame e retirar valores NA

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um dataframe com várias colunas. Como faço para calcular a média de uma das variáveis com base nos valores de outra variável? Eu tenho a frequência de várias espécies encontradas em 4 campanhas e quero calcular a média de cada espécie registrada. Para isso devo somar as frequências observadas pelo número de campanhas realizadas em cada local, mas a função que usei

```
dadomean = dcast(dados, local  ~ especie, mean)
```

calcula a média com base somente nas campanhas que a espécie foi registrada e não utiliza os dados em que o registro foi 0.  assim como a função

```
dadomean = dados %>%
  group_by(local, especie) %>%
  summarise(mean(frequencia))
```

Também tentei

```
dadomean = dcast(dados, local  ~ especie, mean, subset = .(campanha == 4)))
```

mas não aceitou a função e deu esse erro

> Error in .(campanha == 4) : could not find function "."

Também tentei o seguinte e não deu certo.

```
dadomean = dcast(dados, local  ~ especie, mean, na.rm=TRUE, margins = "campanha")
```

E também sempre tem `NA` para aqueles locais onde era para ser `0` e não consegui transformar em `0`.

```js
campanha local especie frequencia
1          A     aa       1
1          A     bb       2
1          A     cc       1
1          B     bb       1
1          B     dd       7
2          A     aa       50
2          A     bb       1
2          A     dd       8
3          A     aa       2
3          B     aa       3
3          B     dd       3
4          A     aa       33
4          A     bb       5
4          A     cc       1
4          A     dd       1
4          B     aa       18
4          B     bb       10
4          B     dd       6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta está bastante confusa. Pergunta por médias da `frequencia` agrupada por `campanha` e depois só dá exemplos de código em que o agrupamento é por `local` e `especie`.

Vou primeiro agrupar por `campanha`.

```
aggregate(frequencia ~ campanha, dados, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#  campanha frequencia
#1        1   2.400000
#2        2  19.666667
#3        3   2.666667
#4        4  10.571429
```

Agora, vou agrupar por `local` e `espécie`, tanto usando o pacote `reshape2` como com a função base `tapply`. Como pode ver os resultados são indênticos, a única diferença é que uma atribui o valor `NaN` quando a média não pode ser calculada e a outra atribui `NA`.
Além disso, para pôr `0` é exatamente da mesma maneira.

```
library(reshape2)

dadomean1 <- dcast(dados, local  ~ especie, mean, value.var = "frequencia")
dadomean1[is.na(dadomean1)] <- 0
dadomean1
#  local   aa       bb  cc       dd
#1     A 21.5 2.666667   1 4.500000
#2     B 10.5 5.500000   0 5.333333


dadomean2 <- with(dados, tapply(frequencia, list(local, especie), mean))
dadomean2[is.na(dadomean2)] <- 0
dadomean2
#    aa       bb cc       dd
#A 21.5 2.666667  1 4.500000
#B 10.5 5.500000  0 5.333333
```

**EDIÇÃO.**

Para calcular as médias das campanhas agrupadas por `especie` e `local` mas tendo em conta todas as campanhas e não só aquelas em que há registro da espécie, o melhor é definir uma função `mediaCamp` que faça esses cálculos.
Depois, usa-se mais uma vez o `aggregate`.

```
mediaCamp <- function(x){
  ncamp <- length(unique(dados$campanha))
  sum(x)/ncamp
}

dadomean3 <- aggregate(frequencia ~ especie + local, dados, mediaCamp)
dadomean3
#  especie local frequencia
#1      aa     A      21.50
#2      bb     A       2.00
#3      cc     A       0.50
#4      dd     A       2.25
#5      aa     B       5.25
#6      bb     B       2.75
#7      dd     B       4.00
```

**DADOS** em formato `dput`.

```
dados <-
structure(list(campanha = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), local = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), especie = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
4L), .Label = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), class = "factor"), frequencia = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 50L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 33L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 
10L, 6L)), .Names = c("campanha", "local", "especie", "frequencia"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: Me desculpe se fui confusa Rui, é que ainda estou aprendendo a fazer as perguntas aqui, e acho difícil colocar a pergunta por escrito da melhor forma. Agradeço sua ajuda, mas é que dessa forma (eu testei aqui) continua a dar o mesmo erro. Ele faz a média com base nas campanhas em que houve registro e não com base em todas as campanhas. Como exemplo, o valor da frequência média da espécie aa no local B deveria ser 5.25 porque é 21 indivíduos/4 campanhas mas quando uso essa função ou as que coloquei na minha pergunta, o valor é 10.5 que é 21 indivíduos/ 2 campanhas (em que a espécie aparece).

Comment: Não sei como incluir que faça a média da frequência com base em todas as campanhas realizadas e não com base nas campanhas em que há o registro da espécie

Comment: @Jussara Assim ficou mais claro. Quer a média com base em todas as campanhas **mesmo que não haja registro da espécie**.

Comment: @Jussara Veja se é isto.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que vc quer.

A média de cada espécie em cada local.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(dados, especie, local)%>%summarise(Total=mean(frequencia))
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo. Os valores duplicaram

Comment: Mas você não queria para cada especie em cada local? Se for somente por especie e local indiferente, é só remover a variável  local da fórmula.