# r - média de uma variável em relação aos valores de outra variável em um data frame dentro de cada agrupamento

Tags: r, data.frame

Essa questão é após uma colocada por mim há pouco tempo. Esse é o link se quiserem acompanhar [r - média de uma variável em relação aos valores de outra variável em um data frame](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317191/r-m%C3%A9dia-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-em-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-aos-valores-de-outra-vari%C3%A1vel-em-um-data-fr/317393?noredirect=1#comment642607_317393)

Tenho um dataframe com várias colunas. Como faço para calcular a média de uma das variáveis com base nos valores de outra variável dentro de um agrupamento de uma das colunas? Ou seja, tenho a frequência de várias espécies encontradas em 4 campanhas divididas em 2 etapas e quero calcular a média de cada espécie registrada em cada local dentro de cada etapa, sendo a média realizada com as campanhas daquela etapa. Ou seja, a média da frequência das espécies é com base em todas as campanhas realizadas dentro daquela etapa e não com base somente nas campanhas em que há o registro da espécie ou com base em TODAS as campanhas, não importando a etapa.
o script que estou usando com base na ajuda de vocês é esse

```js
#somar todos os registros de cada sp no local em cada campanha.

dados_anura = dados_sapo %>%
  group_by(etapa, campanha,  local,  especie) %>%
  summarise(sum(frequencia))
## Vou lá na tabela e troco o nome da coluna "sum(frequencia)" por frequencia
write.table(dados_anura, 'dados_anura.csv', sep = ';', row.names = F)


# Salvo e chamo aqui de novo

dados_anuras <- read.csv("dados_anura.csv", header = TRUE, sep=";")

#média com base em todas as campanhas mesmo que não haja registro da espécie.
# calcular as médias das campanhas agrupadas por especie e local, com todas as campanhas e não só aquelas em que há registro da espécie.
# Definir uma função mediaCamp que faça esses cálculos.Depois, usa-se mais uma vez o aggregate.

mediaCamp <- function(x){
  ncamp <- length(unique(dados_anuras$campanha))
  sum(x)/ncamp
}

dadomean4 <- aggregate(frequencia ~ etapa, local + especie, dados_anuras, mediaCamp)
### Para retirar os NA's
dadomean4[is.na(dadomean4)] <- 0
```

Mas o resultado está dando errado. Dessa forma, o cálculo da média é com base em TODAS as campanhas, e não com base nas campanhas somente daquela etapa, mesmo dando o valor (na célula) para aquela etapa.

```js
etapa  campanha local especie frequencia
A1        1       A     aa       1
A1        1       A     bb       2
A1        1       A     cc       1
A1        1       B     bb       1
A1        1       B     dd       7
A1        2       A     aa       50
A1        2       A     bb       1
A1        2       A     dd       8
A2        3        A   aa       2
A2        3       B     aa       3
A2        3       B     dd       3
A2        4       A     aa       33
A2        4       A     bb       5
A2        4       A     cc       1
A2        4       A     dd       1
A2        4       B     aa       18
A2        4       B     bb       10
A2        4       B     dd       6
```

Comment: Qual seria a saída adequada que você espera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A média de cada **espécie** registrada em cada **local** dentro de cada **etapa**:

```
dplyr::group_by(data, especie, local, etapa) %>% summarise(Total=mean(frequencia))
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   especie, local [?]
#   especie local etapa Total
#   <fct>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
# 1 aa      A     A1     25.5
# 2 aa      A     A2     17.5
# 3 aa      B     A2     10.5
# 4 bb      A     A1      1.5
# 5 bb      A     A2      5  
# 6 bb      B     A1      1  
# 7 bb      B     A2     10  
# 8 cc      A     A1      1  
# 9 cc      A     A2      1  
# 10 dd     A     A1      8  
# 11 dd     A     A2      1  
# 12 dd     B     A1      7  
# 13 dd     B     A2      4.5
```